# How to replace React useState with object?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a drag-n-drop library to re-order a list of components I have on the database, my array contains both item value and unique id I could easily change to numeric.

The library provide an example that use the code below to handle the list data

```
   const [cards, setCards] = useState([
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Write a cool JS library',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Make it generic enough',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Write README',
      },
    ])

  const moveCard = useCallback(
      (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
        const dragCard = cards[dragIndex]
        setCards(
          update(cards, {
            $splice: [
              [dragIndex, 1],
              [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard],
            ],
          }),
        )
      },
      [cards],
    )
```

I am not familiar with hooks and I am not sure how to replace this static data to my already saved remote list, I could pass the array to this example component via props.

The library is react-dnd. Should the id be in order or can it be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your array instead of the one given in useState.

```
const [cards, setCards] = useState(yourArray)
```

That should work.

For your specific example I've added props in example.jsx and passed in via index.js
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-ganguly-mg2m9

Comment: I guess it should work, this is a static component I got error Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/sortable/simple

Comment: Edited. See answer above. @usfslk

Comment: @usfslk Accept if it helped to provide help to other members on SO.